# Migration Alamofire swift2 from swift 3

Tags: swift3, alamofire

Previously in my APP when I was making a call to the server if there were any errors I did the following:

```
Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON{
   response in if let JSON = response.result.value{
       if JSON.count != 0{
           let errorList = JSON["responseErrorsList"] as? NSArray
                for error in errorList!{
                    let erro: String = error as! String
           switch erro{
                 case "PersonRequired":
```

With the migration from swift 2 to swift 4 I am having problems because theList errors comes to nil however the result of JSON is as follows:

```
["Rate": , "Level": , "Code": , "ID": 0, "Zone": , "Address": , "ErrorsListServer": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x17400ba90>( InvalidCode ) , "SubZone": ]
```

Does anyone know how I can access the "ErrorsListServer" field and fetch the errors that in this case is "InvalidCode".

What I have implemented and is not working for is the following:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{
if (JSON as AnyObject).count != 0{
  let errorList = JSON["responseErrorsList"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your JSON response, you need to access key `ErrorsListServer` and it is Array of `String` not Array of `Dictionary` so you need to cast it to `[String]`. Also you can reduce your code with single `if let` statement like this way.

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any], 
   let errorList = JSON["ErrorsListServer"] as? [String] {
      for error in errorList {
          print(error)
      }
}
```